# Kendo Grid issue with dropdown showing [object Object] after first binding

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a `Kendo UI` grid which uses a dropdown as the editor for a field. I'm having problems getting the dropdown to properly bind to the viewModel (at least I think that is the issue). If I make a selection from the dropdown then add a new row or navigate from the row I am on, the field shows [object Object]. Now if I go back to the row and make a different selection and navigate to a different row, it behaves like it should, showing the selection I made. [Here is a js bin](http://jsbin.com/OzOdiLAf/32/edit) showing the behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `SuggestedVendor` type is `string` but when you click `Add New Line Item` link to add new item you set some default value `Id: 1`, `Position: 1` and `SuggestedVendor : null` but it should empty string like `SuggestedVendor : ''`

```
dataSource.add({ Id: 1, SuggestedVendor: (viewModel.suggestedVendor === null) ? '' /* instead of null*/ : viewModel.suggestedVendor.SuggestedVendor, Position:1 });
```

Working [**demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/WzwEDTp9jgK2IxYULLaP?p=preview)

**Note:**
You can set your default value during `datasource` field declaration, for more details [demo for custom editing](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html). In this way you don't need manually handle `$(".k-grid-custom-create").on("click", function (e) {...})`

Comment: Thanks that was it. As for defaulting the value in the `datasource` declaration, I have tried that but I can't find a way to do this dynamically. My app is for creating requisitions and if the user didn't select a default Suggested Vendor when creating the Header (which is bound to viewModel.suggestedVendor) then I leave it blank. I have found that setting the default in the `datasorce` only allows hardcoding it. If you know of a way to dynamically set it, I would like to see a working example. Thanks again!